# can i use adb with powershell to query and adjust apps and settings?

Tags: powershell, adb

Setting up Samsung S20 running android 13, skipped most options manually and about to mass-disable most features, if possible.

Via the phone UI it seems each app must be configured individually.
Is there a way to use adb and something like powershell to query all apps, list all that have notifications enabled, and even disable all?

Same question applies to other settings that are app-based, like: location, draw on screen, admin rights, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can view, list, delete and change settings via settings provider command

```
 $ settings help
Settings provider (settings) commands:
  help
      Print this help text.
  get [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY
      Retrieve the current value of KEY.
  put [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY VALUE [TAG] [default]
      Change the contents of KEY to VALUE.
      TAG to associate with the setting.
      {default} to set as the default, case-insensitive only for global/secure namespace
  delete [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY
      Delete the entry for KEY.
  reset [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE {PACKAGE_NAME | RESET_MODE}
      Reset the global/secure table for a package with mode.
      RESET_MODE is one of {untrusted_defaults, untrusted_clear, trusted_defaults}, case-insensitive
  list [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE
      Print all defined keys.
      NAMESPACE is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive
```

to list the available settings in a specific namespace you can use

```
$ settings list system
```

for example.